# Is it okay to use sleep mode for my laptop all the time?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep

I use many applications every day, so it's important for me to get the complete desktop state (all windows, shells, etc. in the same state they were in, etc.) back instantly when I turn on the computer. Can I use sleep mode all the time (not just during the day, but every night, and anytime I don't use the laptop)? That practically means the computer is never turned off completely, it's always under some power.

Can it hurt some circuitry if the computer is never fully switched off? Or is it OK with today's computers?

Comment: It is arguably even better for modern electronics than frequent power-downs and power-ups.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev  he talks about sleeping when transferring. I'm interested in sleeping even when the computer is not used for a longer period of time. E.g. putting it to sleep for the night, every night, without any exception

Comment: What about updates that require a full restart?

Comment: @DavidPostill updates are installed once a fortnight or so and then I lose the desktop state, but the computer is not powered down even then, because after a restart I rebuild the desktop state and use sleep again until the next restart, so the laptop is under some power all the time. This is the question if it has some negative effect on the hardware in the long run

Comment: @Tom Sleeping 99% of the idle time instead of 90% won't make a huge difference, right?

Comment: I've done exactly that for about three years with my current laptop (apart from taking it away from the house when I shutdown). I've had one problem in that time (failing internal hard disk) which may or may not be related to over sleeping ...

Comment: Here's another one: http://superuser.com/questions/449629/is-sleep-mode-harmful-for-a-computer

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev I don't know, 10% may not be a negligible difference in a system in the long run

Comment: @DavidPostill  some comments mention the battery, is it bad for a battery if it is used all the time? Though my laptop is usually plugged in, so the battery may not be active in this case.

Comment: I'm using the original battery (apparently with execellent battery health, 100% charged) but plugged in to mains 99.99% of the time ... I've hardly used battery only ...

Comment: Keeping the battery charged all the time does reduce its lifetime, but this is not related to sleep mode.

Comment: It can be related to it, because I unplug my computer for the night, so then the battery has to step up to maintain sleep state, but you are right, I'm interested in the generic long term effect of sleep mode on the hardware which includes all parts, not just the battery.